# update a model's field from another model in django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

my models.py is :

```
class clients(models.Model):
    client_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True )
    '
    '
     money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default=0)


class transfermoney(models.Model):
    first_client_id = models.IntegerField()
    second_client_id = models.IntegerField()
    amountofmoney = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

my serializers.py is :

```
class moneytransfer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            clients.objects.get(client_id = data['first_client_id'])
            clients.objects.get(client_id = data['second_client_id'])
        except clients.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("One of the clients does not exist")
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = transfermoney
        fields = ('__all__')
        read_only_fields = ('time','date',)
```

my views.py is :

```
   class transferingmoney(APIView):
        def post(self,request):
            serializer = moneytransfer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                def update(self,data):              
                     client_1 = clients.objects.get(client_id=data['first_client_id'])
                     client_2 = clients.objects.get(client_id=data['second_client_id'])
                     client_1.money -= data['amountofmoney']
                     client_2.money += data['amountofmoney']
                     client_1.save()
                     client_2.save()

                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i'm using django rest framework, when i made a post request to "transferingmoney" , it made a record into the "transfermoney" model table ,, but it did not update the "money" field for client_1 or client_2 in the "clients" model

please can you help me, what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have created the function `update` but never called it. Your view should look like this:

```
class transferingmoney(APIView):
        def post(self,request):
            serializer = moneytransfer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()

                client_1 = clients.objects.get(client_id=serializer.data['first_client_id'])
                client_2 = clients.objects.get(client_id=serializer.data['second_client_id'])
                client_1.money -= serializer.data['amountofmoney']
                client_2.money += serializer.data['amountofmoney']
                client_1.save()
                client_2.save()

                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```